# Fill in a PDF Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

Hi I have a PDF form that needs to be filled in. The app asks questions to the users (form) and when it is submitted the answers should be filled into the PDF blank spaces for printing.

- I'm familiar with JS and Node(haven't used in a while). Not using PHP.
- I will host it at my usual place, Heroku.
- I work on a windows 7 machine

Any tips would be great.

I did some research and [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) kept popping up. according to this it takes HTML pages and converts to PDF. So after the user answers I'll get the answers and make an html file that looks like the PDF with the provided answers filled in at the spaces. (don't know if that's that a good solution)

It says to download the wkhtmltopdf on your machine and run the HTML document through the tool sounds fun. but how will I host this tool on heroku. I was looking for NPM stuff  and I found  [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf). but it also says that "First, you need to install the wkhtmltopdf command line tool on your system" the system is heroku right?

on [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) it says to use `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf`. Does that mean I need to have `wkhtmltopdf` on my system variables? so I could use it in my command line.

PS : I know this is a big question so I'm willing to pay someone 30 dollars to help me work through this. I could do through paypal or something.

Comment: This looks promising.... https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Answer (score 2):

I was working with [html to pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) module , it is great , under the hood it uses phantomjs ( im not a expert at all but it is a good start for me) , i am able to use pdf as a stream or buffer i hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following modules on npm:

- [`fill-pdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fill-pdf)
- [`pdffiller`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdffiller)
- [`pdf-fill-form`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-fill-form)
- [`node-pdffiller`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pdffiller)
- [`pdfkit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit)

The `node-pdffiller`is a wrapper for PDFtk, the PDF Toolkit:

- https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

There's a lot of good documentation on the website of PDFKit:

- http://pdfkit.org/

Those modules have different features and API. You should find something that suits your needs.

There's also a nice article:

- [Generating a PDF with Express & Node.js](https://edgecoders.com/generating-a-pdf-with-express-in-node-js-d3ff5107dff1) by Koen van Gilst (it uses PDFKit)